# How to pronounce "I'm gonna"

Tags: pronunciation

I often hear "I'm gonna".
but sometimes I hear "I'm ona" pronounced by a native speaker as "I'm gonna".
Dose it make sense?

Comment: '*I'm gonna*' isn't standard English, so there are won't be any standard rules for pronunciation. I've even heard '*I'm 'a*' sometimes, too, as in "*When can I expect that report?*" / "*Don't worry, I'm 'a do it now.*"

Comment: You hear "I'm ona" pronounced as "I'm gonna"? What in the world is "I'm ona"?

Comment: It's perfectly standard English. It just isn't written much, because nobody's sure how to spell it, and most people are worried they may be wrong, and that people will laugh. This is what happens when children aren't taught any grammar after third grade; they still carry along all their childhood Angst when dealing with it.

Comment: I can't help but think about the Kanye meme: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/events/kanye-interrupts-imma-let-you-finish

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of [elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision), where consonants and even whole syllables can be lost to make a word easier to say quickly.

In fact, even *I'm gonna* is an example - it is an elided form of *I am going to*. *I'm ona* and *I'ma* are just taking the elision further, but this isn't necessary.

It should be noted that even *I'm gonna* is colloquial, familiar language and can seem childish/uneducated - *I'm ona* and *I'ma* even more so.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it's better not to use that wards?

Comment: It depends on how formal the situation is - among friends, *I'm gonna* is just fine. In a more professional, workplace environment, *I'm going to* would be recommended.