# What is the difference between "going to love" and "gonna love"?

Tags: meaning, orthography

Is there any difference between "you are going to love it " and "you gonna love it"?

Comment: "Gonna" means "going to", but is used more in speech than writing. In writing it's very informal. In speech it's common.

Comment: One is spelled correctly. The other is eye dialect for exactly the same thing.

Comment: @tchrist Uh, no.  Both are spelled correctly. They're pronounced differently and used in different contexts. They're synonymous but not identical.

Comment: @DanBron Must I dig up the Lawler posts about all this? These aren't different things.

Comment: @tchrist That would be a treat. Please do, if you can.

Comment: @DanBron [Enjoy](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gonna.html).

Comment: they're exactly the same in meaning, gonna is just slang.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks! I ended up using a lot of that material in my answer. I don't agree that "eye dialect" means it's the same word misspelled, especially given the evolution of English towards more synthetic forms, but I  do reach the same conclusion that it is dangerous to spell it that way. BTW, I know I've seen John hold court on how normal native speakers almost always use, e.g. "shoulda" instead of "should have" when speaking, but now I can't find those comments. If you happen to remember where he's said such things, I could make my answer more robust.

Comment: related: [How often do people say “gotta”, “wanna” or “gonna” in English speaking countries?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62045/how-often-do-people-say-gotta-wanna-or-gonna-in-english-speaking-countrie) and [How to pronounce “I'm gonna”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116619/how-to-pronounce-im-gonna) and [“I am going to school” = “I am gonna school”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155898/i-am-going-to-school-i-am-gonna-school)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks, I already referenced that in my answer, to support the claim that even very educated speakers pronounce the words this way.

Comment: @DanBron Ya
[yusta](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+yusta)
[shouldna](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+shouldna)
[hafta](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+hafta)
[gonna](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+gonna)
[gotta](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+gotta)
[wanna](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+wanna)
ask that, 
[doncha](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=doncha)
know and 
[aintcha](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=aintcha)
glad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You're gonna get yourself in trouble

To head off suggestions that these words are more than synonymous, but *identical*, let me [cite the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/79914?redirectedFrom=gonna#eid) [paywalled] here:

> #### *gonna*, v.
>
> **Pronunciation**:  Brit.   /ɡənə/, /ˈɡɒnə/,  U.S. /ɡənə/, /ˈɡɔnə/, /ˈɡɑnə/
>   **Forms**:  regional and colloq. (orig. U.S. regional), *gona*, *gonna*; Eng. regional...
>   **Frequency** (in current use):  *****--- (5/8)
>   **Origin**: A̲ ̲v̲a̲r̲i̲a̲n̲t̲ ̲o̲r̲ ̲a̲l̲t̲e̲r̲a̲t̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲o̲f̲ ̲a̲n̲o̲t̲h̲e̲r̲ ̲l̲e̲x̲i̲c̲a̲l̲ ̲i̲t̲e̲m̲. Etymon: English *going to*.
>   **Etymology**:  Representing a regional and colloquial pronunciation of *going to* (see *go* v.), with reduction of the unstressed vowel and assimilatory loss of the initial consonant of the second element.
>   *colloq*.
>
> 1. With auxiliary be: going to (see go v. 51a(a)).
> 2. As a simple modal auxiliary, followed by the bare infinitive.
>      a. Used to express a plan or intention, or to make a prediction.
>      (a) Am (or is, etc.) going to (see go v. 51a(b)).
>
> ... [more definitions follow]

So *going to* and *gonna* are two separate words (well, lexemes) used in different circumstances.

**Broadly, one *writes* "going to" but one *says* "gonna"** (not always, but frequently).

#### Spoken vs Written language

Thanks to [@tchrist in the comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380105/what-is-the-difference-between-going-to-love-and-gonna-love?noredirect=1#comment894295_380105), here is an analysis from our resident linguist, [Prof. John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler), where [he posted a message to the alt.usage.english Usenet group](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gonna.html):

> Yup.  "gonna" is an accepted "eye dialect" spelling for the
>   most common American pronunciation of the "(be) going (to)"
>   future construction, as in "I'm gonna kick some butt".
>
> In standard written English, this would be written "I'm going to kick
>   some butt", but if it were pronounced like that, as /aym gowIng tuw kIk s@m b@t/, it would most likely be interpreted as a joke.
>
> [The word] "gonna" is actually pronounced /g@'n@/, with a "flap n" that has a faint /t/-echo; the stress is on the first shwa.  It's natural and very common for auxiliary verbs -- especially modal auxiliary verbs -- and their contractions to change from their original roots. They're used so
>   frequently that people fall into habits of dealing with them, especially
>   if the individual words that originally made up the construction have lost
>   their individual meanings and now form a fixed phrase.

And, later in the same message:

> Eye dialect is largely used to represent speech in narratives, and
>   often carries the (author's) presumption that the speaker is
>   illiterate or of a lower class.  **It's not at all standard in normal
>   written English**, except occasionally on the net, where we sometimes
>   want to invoke the conversational rules and milieu of spoken
>   communication.
>
> ***Don't*** use these words in any formal writing.  On the other hand,
>   if the person(s) you're writing for can be trusted not to put you
>   down for your writing, go right ahead and use them.  And if you're
>   writing a story and want to represent speech, be aware that the
>   socioeconomic class of the character speaking (or rather the
>   reader's perception of that class) is affected by the author's
>   use of eye dialect.

To expand on this analysis a bit, drawing from [this BBC World Service column](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv165.shtml) linked to from [@Ice-9's answer to a prior question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/155919/55623) which [@MariLouA highlighted](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380105/what-is-the-difference-between-going-to-love-and-gonna-love#comment894320_380105) in the comments:

> *Gonna* [is used] **to express the *going to* form of the future is used with first second and third person singular and plural**. Note that in the interrogative, *are* is omitted in second person singular and first and second person plural

That is, you would say "I'm gonna eat a pie [in the future]" instead of "I am going to eat a pie", but you would **not** say *"I'm gonna store" instead of "I'm going to the store" (but you *could* say "I'm gonna store *the pie in the fridge*" or "I'm gonna *go to* the store"; doncha love English?).

#### English is gonna change

So why this distinction between spoken *gonna* and written *going to*?

In short: English is an analytic language (expresses meaning through arrangement of separate words, aka *syntax*), but there is a well-established pattern of analytic languages slowly transforming into synthetic languages (expressing meaning through changing individual words, aka *morphology*):

[image: image of the grammaticalization cycle, highlighting transitional words in English like *gonna*]

<sub>source: *[The Grammaticalization Cycle](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/TheGrammaticalizationCycle.pdf)*, Prof. John Lawler (undated)</sub>

So what you see here, with people pronouncing *going to* as *gonna*, are "[transitional fossils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transitional_fossils)"¹ of English slowly (~1K years) transforming from analytic to synthetic.

But as writing lags speech, so even where someone would *say* "gonna" (which is **[very common, even among the educated](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/62057/55623)**²), he would *still write* "going to".

It will take a long time for conscientious English speakers to actually write `g o n n a` in anything but the most informal settings³, or, as Dr. Lawler points out, when imitating colloquial speech intentionally in writing to give a story a more grounded flavor.

---

¹  <sub>Technically, the "transitional fossils" would be exactly when people *wrote down* words like "gonna". The spoken forms are more like the ephemeral soft tissue in monsters of epochs past. Unrecoverable.</sub>

² <sub>I know I've seen Dr. Lawler explain in comments [not answers] here that fused words like "gonna", "hafta", "wanna" are the *standard* among native speakers when speaking, and that only in the most stilted and unnatural cirumstances are the full "going to", "have to", "want to" actually enunciated.</sub>

<sub>Unfortunately, I cannot find that comment now nor relevant posts either here on EL&U or our sister site [Linguistics.se](http://https:/linguistics.stackexchange.com/), so I can't confirm the scope of that assertion. It might only be certain fused forms or in certain situations. If anyone has any pointers, leave a comment, and I'll incorporate the information.</sub>

³ <sub>Anecdotally, I personally find myself writing *wanna*, *gonna*, etc in places I wouldn't have considered in years past. Things like text messages or IMs to close friends or family. And bear in mind that I'm one of those people who always properly capitalizes and punctuates text messages, and outright refuses to use modern innovations like *u* (*you*) or *ur* (*your*/*you're*).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The word *gonna* is the informal version. It's basically slang.

I would never write it in a paper, letter, email etc, but I probably use it a lot in friendly, casual speech.

> #### Gonna
>
> (CONTRACTION)
>   *informal*: **Going to**.

<sub>source: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gonna)</sub>

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this answer or why. It at least cites a dictionary, which makes it better than 95% of the answers here, plus it provides useful guidance from a native speaker. Probably someone downvoted because we don't like answering questions here that the OP could have easily answered for himself with minimal research, or perhaps it's the misspelling of "etc" or the lack of capitalization of your first sentence (this is a site full of English pedants, after all). Anyway I'm going to edit your answer and vote it up.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and editing! I'm no expert, I'm on this site to learn more than anything else so thank you for being constructive rather than just negative.

Comment: *Gonna* is unrelated to slang. *Flyboys   on the prowl for some splash and dash* is slang. See the difference?

Comment: @tchrist *Slang* is slang for *informal*. Or *slang* informally means *informal*.  See what I did there?

Comment: @tchrist Totally unrelated? It may just be a quick google search but the first dictionary definition of slang I find is; "a type of language consisting of words and phrases that are regarded as very informal, are more common in speech than writing, and are typically restricted to a particular context or group of people."

Is "gonna" not considered informal, more common in speech than writing and typically restricted to particular contexts or groups of people?

Comment: Not on site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.  These terms have technical meanings that should be used correctly or not at all

Comment: I think you may be holding this question and my answer to slightly higher standards than are required in this situation. If the question was longer with more detail about the origin of the query your input might be helpful, but since short, undefined questions like this tend to be about the everyday use of words (by people who might not be  linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts) you just appear pedantic and overbearing. Maybe try reading your audience and adjusting the level of detail you give to the complexity of the question.

Comment: @DanBron, just an observation of something that stood out because I'm not used to seeing it on the SE.  On the technical sites I frequent, people seem to always use "upvote it".  Guess I shouldn't be surprised to find the correct "vote it up" on an English site.  :-)

Comment: I made your same point in more morphosyntax-nerdy language. I read Dr. Lawler's write-up on this that @tchrist pointed me to, and having done so I still dispute his claim that *gonna* is spelled incorrectly, or is the same lexeme as "going to", but misspelled. It's a separate, related, lexeme, used more in speech than in writing, just as you say. But I can only upvote you once, so I can't help more.